# WPF - ODP.NET Managed Driver not working on clients without Oracle client installed

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle

I have a .NET WPF application (Framework 4) that I'm using the Oracle managed ODP.NET driver with, and it is having issues on machines (x64) that don't have an Oracle client installed.  I don't understand why, since one of the benefits of the managed driver I thought was to avoid having to install an Oracle client.  The error getting return when trying to open a connection is this:

System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater

I'm referencing the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess dll in my project, and I also have this in the App.config:

```
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
  <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver"
       invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
       description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
       type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess,Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

Any thoughts as to what might be going on here ?

Thanks

Comment: I guess, you may have to download and use XCopy deployment version. Refer to this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Data.OracleClient Indicates that you are still referencing the old (and now deprecated) Oracle Client somewhere in your code.  Make sure that the reference is removed and that it is no longer mentioned in your web.config.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using LLBLGEN and it is referencing the client.  I'm troubleshooting with them now..

Comment: Perfect!  Good luck getting a solution in place.